# Build error while compiling twrp for moto g(40) fusion

Tags: android, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was compiling twrp for moto g40 fusion codenamed hanoip using kernel sources, but got this error
**/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matchin`"'**

**/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file**

I got this error when

`BOARD_USES_RECOVERY_AS_BOOT := true`

But after changing the value to **false** everything was fine.

The problem here is that **BOARD_USES_RECOVERY_AS_BOOT** must be **true** for twrp to boot.

here is the build log when `BOARD_USES_RECOVERY_AS_BOOT := true`

```
20:48:30 You are building on a machine with 7.69GB of RAM
20:48:30 
20:48:30 The minimum required amount of free memory is around 16GB,
20:48:30 and even with that, some configurations may not work.
20:48:30 
20:48:30 If you run into segfaults or other errors, try reducing your
20:48:30 -j value.
20:48:30 ************************************************************
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=127
TARGET_PRODUCT=twrp_hanoip
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=arm
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a9
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-5.10.60.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2-x86_64-Ubuntu-20.04-LTS
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=RQ1A.210205.004
OUT_DIR=out
PRODUCT_SOONG_NAMESPACES=device/motorola/hanoip
============================================
ninja: no work to do.
ninja: no work to do.
No need to regenerate ninja file
No need to regenerate ninja file
No need to regenerate ninja file
Starting ninja...
[  0% 1/3773] target  C++: recovery <= bootable/recovery/twrp.cpp
FAILED: out/target/product/hanoip/obj/EXECUTABLES/recovery_intermediates/twrp.o
/bin/bash -c "PWD=/proc/self/cwd  prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/clang-r383902b/bin/clang++ -I system/core/fs_mgr/libfs_avb/include -I system/core/fs_mgr/include_fstab -I system/core/fs_mgr/include -I system/core/fs_mgr/libdm/include -I system/core/fs_mgr/liblp/include -I system/gsid/include -I system/core/init -I system/extras/ext4_utils/include -I bionic -I system/extras -I system/core/adb -I system/core/libmodprobe/include -I system/core/libsparse -I external/zlib -I system/core/libziparchive/include -I external/freetype/include -I external/boringssl/include -I external/libcxx/include -I external/libselinux/include -I external/libpng -I bootable/recovery/gui/include -I bootable/recovery/recovery_ui/include -I bootable/recovery/otautil/include -I bootable/recovery/install/include -I bootable/recovery/fuse_sideload/include -I bootable/recovery/install/include -I bootable/recovery/twrpinstall/include -I bootable/recovery/recovery_utils/include -I bootable/recovery/libpixelflinger/include -I bootable/recovery/minuitwrp/include -I bootable/recovery/twinstall/include -I system/extras/ext4_utils -I external/boringssl/src/include -I bootable/recovery/crypto -I bootable/recovery/crypto/fscrypt -I system/vold -I bootable/recovery -I out/target/product/hanoip/obj/EXECUTABLES/recovery_intermediates -I out/target/product/hanoip/gen/EXECUTABLES/recovery_intermediates -I libnativehelper/include_jni -Isystem/core/fs_mgr/include -Isystem/core/fs_mgr/include -Isystem/core/fs_mgr/libfiemap/include -Isystem/core/logwrapper/include -Isystem/core/fs_mgr/libdm/include -Iexternal/e2fsprogs/lib/uuid -Iexternal/e2fsprogs/lib -Isystem/extras/libfscrypt/include -Isystem/core/fs_mgr/include_fstab -Isystem/core/fs_mgr/libfs_avb/include -Isystem/core/fs_mgr/liblp/include -Ihardware/libhardware/include -Isystem/media/audio/include -Isystem/core/libcutils/include -Isystem/core/libsystem/include -Isystem/bt/types -Isystem/libhidl/base/include -Isystem/libhidl/transport/include -Isystem/libhwbinder/include -Isystem/core/base/include -Iexternal/fmtlib/include -Isystem/core/libutils/include -Isystem/core/libbacktrace/include -Isystem/core/liblog/include -Isystem/core/libsystem/include -Isystem/core/libcutils/include -Isystem/core/libprocessgroup/include -Iout/soong/.intermediates/system/libhidl/transport/manager/1.0/android.hidl.manager@1.0_genc++_headers/gen -Iout/soong/.intermediates/system/libhidl/transport/manager/1.1/android.hidl.manager@1.1_genc++_headers/gen -Iout/soong/.intermediates/system/libhidl/transport/manager/1.2/android.hidl.manager@1.2_genc++_headers/gen -Iout/soong/.intermediates/system/libhidl/transport/base/1.0/android.hidl.base@1.0_genc++_headers/gen -Iout/soong/.intermediates/hardware/interfaces/boot/1.0/android.hardware.boot@1.0_genc++_headers/gen -Isystem/libhidl/base/include -Isystem/libhidl/transport/include -Isystem/libhwbinder/include -Isystem/core/base/include -Iexternal/fmtlib/include -Isystem/core/libutils/include -Isystem/core/libbacktrace/include -Isystem/core/liblog/include -Isystem/core/libsystem/include -Isystem/core/libcutils/include -Isystem/core/libprocessgroup/include -Iout/soong/.intermediates/system/libhidl/transport/manager/1.0/android.hidl.manager@1.0_genc++_headers/gen -Iout/soong/.intermediates/system/libhidl/transport/manager/1.1/android.hidl.manager@1.1_genc++_headers/gen -Iout/soong/.intermediates/system/libhidl/transport/manager/1.2/android.hidl.manager@1.2_genc++_headers/gen -Iout/soong/.intermediates/system/libhidl/transport/base/1.0/android.hidl.base@1.0_genc++_headers/gen -Iout/soong/.intermediates/hardware/interfaces/boot/1.0/android.hardware.boot@1.0_genc++_headers/gen -Iout/soong/.intermediates/hardware/interfaces/boot/1.1/android.hardware.boot@1.1_genc++_headers/gen -Iexternal/protobuf/src -Iexternal/protobuf/src -Isystem/core/fs_mgr/liblp/include -Isystem/core/fs_mgr/liblp/include -Isystem/core/libutils/include -Isystem/core/libbacktrace/include -Isystem/core/liblog/include -Isystem/core/libsystem/include -Isystem/core/libcutils/include -Isystem/core/libprocessgroup/include -Isystem/libhidl/base/include -Isystem/libhidl/transport/include -Isystem/libhidl/base/include -Isystem/libhidl/transport/include -Isystem/libhwbinder/include -Isystem/core/base/include -Iexternal/fmtlib/include -Isystem/core/libutils/include -Isystem/core/libbacktrace/include -Isystem/core/liblog/include -Isystem/core/libsystem/include -Isystem/core/libcutils/include -Isystem/core/libprocessgroup/include -Iout/soong/.intermediates/system/libhidl/transport/manager/1.0/android.hidl.manager@1.0_genc++_headers/gen -Iout/soong/.intermediates/system/libhidl/transport/manager/1.1/android.hidl.manager@1.1_genc++_headers/gen -Iout/soong/.intermediates/system/libhidl/transport/manager/1.2/android.hidl.manager@1.2_genc++_headers/gen -Iout/soong/.intermediates/system/libhidl/transport/base/1.0/android.hidl.base@1.0_genc++_headers/gen -Iexternal/zlib -Iexternal/zlib -Isystem/core/libcutils/include -Isystem/core/libprocessgroup/include       -Ibootable/recovery/bootloader_message/include -Ibootable/recovery/bootloader_message/include   -Iexternal/libcxx/include -Iexternal/libcxxabi/include  -Iexternal/boringssl/src/include -Isystem/core/base/include -Iexternal/fmtlib/include -Isystem/core/libziparchive/include -Isystem/core/libziparchive/include -Iexternal/googletest/googletest/include -Isystem/core/base/include -Iexternal/fmtlib/include -Iexternal/selinux/libselinux/include     -Isystem/core/libstats/socket/include  -Isystem/libhidl/base/include -Isystem/libhidl/transport/include -Isystem/libhwbinder/include -Isystem/core/base/include -Iexternal/fmtlib/include -Isystem/core/libutils/include -Isystem/core/libbacktrace/include -Isystem/core/liblog/include -Isystem/core/libsystem/include -Isystem/core/libcutils/include -Isystem/core/libprocessgroup/include -Iout/soong/.intermediates/system/libhidl/transport/manager/1.0/android.hidl.manager@1.0_genc++_headers/gen -Iout/soong/.intermediates/system/libhidl/transport/manager/1.1/android.hidl.manager@1.1_genc++_headers/gen -Iout/soong/.intermediates/system/libhidl/transport/manager/1.2/android.hidl.manager@1.2_genc++_headers/gen -Iout/soong/.intermediates/system/libhidl/transport/base/1.0/android.hidl.base@1.0_genc++_headers/gen -Iout/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/hardware/interfaces/stats/1.0/android.frameworks.stats@1.0_genc++_headers/gen -Isystem/libhidl/base/include -Isystem/libhidl/transport/include -Isystem/libhwbinder/include -Isystem/core/base/include -Iexternal/fmtlib/include -Isystem/core/libutils/include -Isystem/core/libbacktrace/include -Isystem/core/liblog/include -Isystem/core/libsystem/include -Isystem/core/libcutils/include -Isystem/core/libprocessgroup/include -Iout/soong/.intermediates/system/libhidl/transport/manager/1.0/android.hidl.manager@1.0_genc++_headers/gen -Iout/soong/.intermediates/system/libhidl/transport/manager/1.1/android.hidl.manager@1.1_genc++_headers/gen -Iout/soong/.intermediates/system/libhidl/transport/manager/1.2/android.hidl.manager@1.2_genc++_headers/gen -Iout/soong/.intermediates/system/libhidl/transport/base/1.0/android.hidl.base@1.0_genc++_headers/gen -Iout/soong/.intermediates/hardware/interfaces/authsecret/1.0/android.hardware.authsecret@1.0_genc++_headers/gen -Isystem/libhidl/base/include -Isystem/libhidl/transport/include -Isystem/libhwbinder/include -Isystem/core/base/include -Iexternal/fmtlib/include -Isystem/core/libutils/include -Isystem/core/libbacktrace/include -Isystem/core/liblog/include -Isystem/core/libsystem/include -Isystem/core/libcutils/include -Isystem/core/libprocessgroup/include -Iout/soong/.intermediates/system/libhidl/transport/manager/1.0/android.hidl.manager@1.0_genc++_headers/gen -Iout/soong/.intermediates/system/libhidl/transport/manager/1.1/android.hidl.manager@1.1_genc++_headers/gen -Iout/soong/.intermediates/system/libhidl/transport/manager/1.2/android.hidl.manager@1.2_genc++_headers/gen -Iout/soong/.intermediates/system/libhidl/transport/base/1.0/android.hidl.base@1.0_genc++_headers/gen -Iout/soong/.intermediates/hardware/interfaces/oemlock/1.0/android.hardware.oemlock@1.0_genc++_headers/gen -Iexternal/libcxx/include -Iexternal/libcxxabi/include -D__LIBC_API__=10000 -Ibionic/libc/include -D__LIBM_API__=10000 -D__LIBM_API__=10000 -D__LIBDL_API__=10000 -Iexternal/avb -Ibootable/recovery/twrpinstall/include -Ibootable/recovery/recovery_ui/include  -Iexternal/libcap/libcap/include -Iout/soong/.intermediates/system/apex/apexd/sysprop/libcom.android.sysprop.apex/android_arm64_armv8-a_static/gen/sysprop/include -Iout/soong/.intermediates/system/core/init/sysprop/libcom.android.sysprop.init/android_arm64_armv8-a_static/gen/sysprop/include -Iexternal/protobuf/src -Iout/soong/.intermediates/system/core/init/libinit/android_arm64_armv8-a_static/gen/proto/system/core/init -Iout/soong/.intermediates/system/core/init/libinit/android_arm64_armv8-a_static/gen/proto -Isystem/core/fs_mgr/libsnapshot/include -Isystem/core/fs_mgr/libfiemap/include -Iexternal/e2fsprogs/lib/uuid -Iexternal/e2fsprogs/lib -Isystem/extras/ext4_utils/include -Isystem/core/fs_mgr/include_fstab -Iexternal/protobuf/src -Iout/soong/.intermediates/system/update_engine/update_metadata-protos/android_arm64_armv8-a_static/gen/proto -Iout/soong/.intermediates/system/core/fs_mgr/libsnapshot/libsnapshot_nobinder/android_arm64_armv8-a_static/gen/proto  -Isystem/core/libmodprobe/include -Iexternal/libcxxabi/include   -I system/core/include -I system/media/audio/include -I hardware/libhardware/include -I hardware/libhardware_legacy/include -I hardware/ril/include -I frameworks/native/include -I frameworks/native/opengl/include -isystem out/target/product/hanoip/obj/include -isystem bionic/libc/include -isystem bionic/libc/kernel/uapi -isystem bionic/libc/kernel/uapi/asm-arm64 -isystem bionic/libc/kernel/android/scsi -isystem bionic/libc/kernel/android/uapi -c  -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -DANDROID -fmessage-length=0 -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -no-canonical-prefixes -DNDEBUG -UDEBUG -fno-exceptions -Wno-multichar -O2 -g -fno-strict-aliasing -Werror=date-time -Werror=pragma-pack -Werror=pragma-pack-suspicious-include -fdebug-prefix-map=/proc/self/cwd= -D__compiler_offsetof=__builtin_offsetof -faddrsig -Werror=int-conversion -fexperimental-new-pass-manager -Wno-reserved-id-macro -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fcolor-diagnostics -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-defaulted-function-deleted -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override -Wno-c99-designator -ftrivial-auto-var-init=zero -enable-trivial-auto-var-init-zero-knowing-it-will-be-removed-from-clang -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-short-enums -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -Wa,--noexecstack -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Werror=format-security -nostdlibinc -march=armv8-a  -Bprebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/aarch64-linux-android/bin  -Wsign-promo -Wimplicit-fallthrough -D_LIBCPP_ENABLE_THREAD_SAFETY_ANNOTATIONS -Wno-gnu-include-next -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -std=gnu++17   -fno-rtti -Wall -Werror -DTW_DEVICE_VERSION='\"-0\"' -DPLATFORM_SDK_VERSION=30 -DRECOVERY_API_VERSION=3 -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-function -DAB_OTA_UPDATER=1 -DPRODUCT_USE_DYNAMIC_PARTITIONS=1 -DTW_GIT_REVISION='\"45a8d148\"' -DBOARD_USES_RECOVERY_AS_BOOT -DTW_HAS_MTP -DRECOVERY_SDCARD_ON_DATA -DCUSTOM_LUN_FILE=\\\"/config/usb_gadget/g1/functions/mass_storage.0/lun.%d/file\\\" -DTW_HAS_EDL_MODE -DTW_LOAD_VENDOR_MODULES=\"mpq-adapter.ko mpq-dmx-hw-plugin.ko qca_cld3_wlan.ko rdbg.ko exfat.ko mmi_sys_temp.ko sensors_class.ko utags.ko moto_f_usbnet.ko watchdogtest.ko mmi_info.ko mmi_annotate.ko tzlog_dump.ko watchdog_cpu_ctx.ko fpsensor_spi_tee.ko fpc1020_mmi.ko ilitek_v3_mmi.ko sx933x_sar.ko snd_smartpa_aw882xx.ko qpnp_adaptive_charge.ko \\\" -DTW_INCLUDE_CRYPTO -DUSE_FSCRYPT -Wno-macro-redefined -DTW_INCLUDE_FBE -DTW_INCLUDE_FBE_METADATA_DECRYPT -DTW_BRIGHTNESS_PATH=\"/sys/class/backlight/panel0-backlight/brightness\" -DTW_MAX_BRIGHTNESS=2047 -DTW_DEFAULT_BRIGHTNESS=1000fo -DTW_EXCLUDE_ENCRYPTED_BACKUPS -DQCOM_RTC_FIX -DHAVE_CAPABILITIES -DTW_USE_NEW_MINADBD -DTW_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=en -fPIE -DANDROID_STRICT -target aarch64-linux-android10000   -Werror=int-to-pointer-cast -Werror=pointer-to-int-cast -Werror=fortify-source -Werror=address-of-temporary -Werror=return-type -Wno-tautological-constant-compare -Wno-tautological-type-limit-compare -Wno-reorder-init-list -Wno-implicit-int-float-conversion -Wno-int-in-bool-context -Wno-sizeof-array-div -Wno-tautological-overlap-compare -Wno-deprecated-copy -Wno-range-loop-construct -Wno-misleading-indentation -Wno-zero-as-null-pointer-constant -Wno-deprecated-anon-enum-enum-conversion -Wno-deprecated-enum-enum-conversion -Wno-string-compare -Wno-enum-enum-conversion -Wno-enum-float-conversion -Wno-pessimizing-move  -MD -MF out/target/product/hanoip/obj/EXECUTABLES/recovery_intermediates/twrp.d -o out/target/product/hanoip/obj/EXECUTABLES/recovery_intermediates/twrp.o bootable/recovery/twrp.cpp"
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
[  0% 2/3773] target  C++: recovery <= bootable/recovery/twrpTar.cpp
FAILED: out/target/product/hanoip/obj/EXECUTABLES/recovery_intermediates/twrpTar.o
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
20:48:34 ninja failed with: exit status 1

[0;31m#### failed to build some targets (4 seconds) ####[00m
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error usually occurs when using wsl. I didnt get this error on to virual-box or installing ubuntu.
Its better to use acthual linux distro rather than using wsl or virtual-box for compiling twrp, kernel or any aosp

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell for sure, but (from past experience) this sounds like either a combination of:

*Possible cause #1:*

- A script failing to properly wrap something like `$PWD` in double-quotes when accessing it.
- The script being called from a directory with characters in it (such as a space or a quote) that needs to be quoted.  Since you are using WSL, I often would suspect that you may have the project on a Windows drive.

OR

*Possible cause #2:*

- A script failing to properly wrap `$PATH` in double-quotes when modifying it.
- And, since you have this tagged WSL, the Windows path having characters in the path (like spaces) that always need quoting.
- And, the interop feature of WSL that automatically appends the Windows path to the Linux path at startup so that you can run Windows commands (assuming the `.exe` is included) such as `powershell.exe`, Visual Studio Code, and (of course) many others.

In the first case, try building in a different directory, preferably something like `~/src`.

In the second case ...

Usually I would recommend finding and fixing the quoting issue as the first step, but:

1. These aren't your scripts
2. You don't need to fix this on a *permanent* basic, just while you are building.

So in this case, I'd recommend trying the build with the Windows path propagation turned off (temporarily).  To do this:

```
sudo -e /etc/wsl.conf
```

And add the following:

```
[interop]
appendWindowsPath=false
```

Save, exit the editor, and exit WSL.

From PowerShell, issue:

```
wsl --shutdown # or wsl --terminate <distro>
```

Then restart WSL.

`echo $PATH` to confirm that the Windows path has not been appended, then try the build again.

Regardless, I recommend setting the `appendWindowsPath` back to `true` (the default) when you are done for that functionality.

Comment: The error was not fixed

Comment: @BhaveshMankar Edited the answer in the interim with an additional possible cause.  Not sure if you saw it before trying the other one.  Are you building from a Windows drive, or under the WSL/Linux filesystem?

Comment: That was informational

Comment: I am building on wsl

Comment: Is there any way by which I can edit the /bin/bash -c "..." command executed while compiling

Comment: Yes, but we need to find the actual cause of the error first.  It appears to be in that 13,000+ character line in your output :-).  I pasted it into Vim and searched for `"`, but everything I saw seemed to be quoted properly (at first glance) -- All double-quotes *inside* the main string were escaped with `\"`.

Comment: Also checked `getconf ARG_MAX` under WSL, and it's showing a 2 million character limit, so length doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: Can there be some issue with the kernel sources I am using. https://github.com/bhawesh2002/kernel_motorola_hanoip

Comment: @BhaveshMankar I'm happy to give it a shot here.  What dependencies did you need?  Also, what WSL distribution are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu-20.04 on wsl2

Comment: I need kernel sources or prebuilt sources and device tree for the device I am building twrp for

Comment: @BhaveshMankar What compiler, Python, etc did you install?  I installed `build-essential`, but that's apparently not right.  It also seems the build scripts are looking for the older `python` command which isn't found on Ubuntu since it only supports Python3.  I'm in a throwaway test instance, so I can install any dependencies needed.  Just need to know which (without doing the research on my own ;-).

Comment: I am using clang to build kernel sources